# Colour all rows with the same colour until value of a cell is not the same as in the previous row anymore

Tags: excel, excel-formula, conditional-formatting

I have the below Excel-table:

```
         |    A      |    B
---------|-----------|---------------
    1    |    500    |
    2    |    500    |
    3    |    500    |
---------|-----------|----------------
    4    |    600    |
    5    |    600    |
---------------------|----------------
    6    |    300    |
---------------------|----------------
    7    |    800    |
    8    |    800    |
    9    |    800    |
---------------------|----------------
    10   |    200    |
    11   |    200    |
---------------------|----------------
    12   |    900    |
---------------------|----------------
    13   |    100    |
    14   |    100    |
```

In `Column A` there a different numbers which can appear multiple times within the rows. 
Now I am looking for a `conditional formatting` that identifies if a number **has switched** compared to the previous row and if so **all the other rows** with the **same number** are coloured in `yellow` **until it switches again**. 
The result should look like this:

[image]

Do you have any idea what kind of `conditional formatting` I need to achive this?

Comment: Can you tell us what version of Excel you are using plz?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Select column A
- Insert new conditional formatting rule based on formula and use:

If one has Excel O365:

```
=ISEVEN(COUNT(UNIQUE(A$1:A1)))
```

Older versions of Excel could use:

```
=ISEVEN(SUMPRODUCT(1/COUNTIF(A$1:A1,A$1:A1)))
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Although I am using Office 365 MSO as Excel version I had to go with your second option in order to make it work.

Comment: What do I need to modify if I want to have the entire row in yellow and not only Column A?

Comment: Select the entire sheet before you apply the rule. Mind you, conditional formatting is volatile and will slow down your workbook!

Comment: I don't know why but somehow it did not work on my side. I opened a second question with screenshots for it. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63844353/apply-conditional-formatting-to-entire-sheet-not-only-to-one-column

Comment: I would incline to use Frequency for earlier versions of Excel which is supposed to be faster - something like =ISEVEN(SUMPRODUCT(--(FREQUENCY(A$1:A1,A$1:A1)>0))) - not worth putting as a separate answer though.