# Apply conditional formatting to entire sheet (not only to one column)

Tags: excel, excel-formula, conditional-formatting

I use the conditional formatting `=ISEVEN(SUMPRODUCT(1/COUNTIF(A$1:A1,A$1:A1)))` from **[this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63843095/colour-all-rows-with-the-same-colour-until-value-of-a-cell-is-not-the-same-as-in/63843482#63843482)**  which works perfectly. 
However, it somehow only applies to `Column A` although I tried to run it over the entire sheet.

The setup currently looks like this: 
*(Sorry for only having it available in German)*

**Screenshot 1:**

[image]

**Screenshot 2:**

[image]

What do I need to change so it applies to the **entire sheet** and **each row is completely** coloured yellow and not only within `Column A`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All you need to change is:

- Select whole sheet
- Apply conditional formatting rules based on formula and use:

  ```
  =ISEVEN(SUMPRODUCT(1/COUNTIF($A$1:$A1,$A$1:$A1)))
  ```

The difference is found in absolute vs. relative column references.

Comment: Yeah. Now I see the issue. It is A$1:A1,A$1:A1 vs. $A$1:$A1,$A$1:$A1